# Using $_GET in a PHP file to display appropriate content

Tags: php

How do you use `$_GET` and when do you use `$_GET`? What exactly does `$_GET` do? I know it is important to use if I want to display user-based content.

Answer (score 3):

The `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals can be used to fetch information that was passed in the HTTP request following either of these protocols respectively.

`$_GET` data will be passed in the url as part of a query string, where as `$_POST` data will be embedded in the request itself.

You can use these arrays for form submissions, web service calls or any other request that would send parameters.

To read about the other superglobals:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Good luck learning.

Comment: @Dagon - I agree entirely, but given the scope of the original question I thought something pretty basic was called for.

Comment: there are many basic sites far better than that one. the php manual the w3c manual et al.The very first line on it about $_GET is wrong

Answer (score 1):

please refer such questions to the manual:

[$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: I think that would have been a good comment but it's IMO not enough for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is for getting the request parameters when URL/form is submitted, normally shows the values in the URL.

For large/secure data, you should use `$_POST` collection, where the form method must be "POST".
Also you can use `$_REQUEST` collection which can be GET or POST collections combinations.

Comment: The only security provided by POST is that it stops data being recorded in server logs. If you want real security you need SSL. Request also mixes in other things (such as cookies), don't use it, make sure you know where your data is coming from.

Answer (score -1):

`$_GET` variables are passed in the URL bar. For example: http://site.com/index.php?var=infohere
`$_POST` are not shown in the URL bar. Pretty much `$_POST` are a little bit more difficult to see.

More info here: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Answer (score -1):

Get is used to carry data to the sever and around the script.
It can be used when posting data in forms or in links.

```
<form action="someactions" method="GET"></form>
```

or in links as

```
http://mylink.com/id="200"

use get to obtain the id
$id=$_GET['id'];
echo $id; //Returns 200 value of id
```

Google to find more on use of get.
Note: Get is discouraged compared to post because of its security issues. It displays your content in the url.Use post where you can

Comment: Get is not discouraged at all. It is very useful for what it is designed for. Imagine being unable to link to a set of search results. Displaying content in a URL is not a problem, people who could read it on the client could read it being typed into the form in the first place. While GET requests do have their data recorded in access logs by default, that can be eliminated by configuring the server to do so.

Comment: I agree with you when it comes to url. I meant GET is discourage when used in posting form data,post is used because the data will not be displayed in the url during the action. In my first code example I was just showing how it can be used in forms.But POST is encouraged in this state unless what you are doing demands it.Kindly let me know if I'm ok on that.

Comment: The only reason that GET is discouraged when posting form data is that *posting* form data uses POST by definition. There is nothign wrong with get forms. See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9) for when to use post and when to use get.

Comment: <9.1.1 second paragraph from the link>GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval.

Comment: and that is what i was trying to say

Comment: That has nothing to do with security at all though.

Comment: Imaging posting form in a cyber cafe using $_GET and it displays your passwords on the url. myexample.com/username=kiu&password=felix. Post handles this in a nice manner.I believe one should use encryption then when using get in forms.